# Best Way to repeatedly make API calls to a server with a constant time interval

Tags: javascript, optimization, setinterval, fetch-api

I am working on a project which requires me to make api calls every minute and then process the data.

Currently I am using **SetInterval Method** in Javascript along with a fetch call .

But I am wondering if this is the best way to do this process. Or what are the drawbacks of using setInterval to make api calls repeatedly and show the processed data on the client.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
const timeInterval = 10000;

setInterval(() => {
  fetch("https://api.solscan.io/nft/market/trade?offset=0&limit=10")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => processTradingData(result));
}, timeInterval);
```

Please Feel free to **suggest better ways to do this**, **Current approaches drawback**.
I have plans to make this into a full-fldged product [So please let me know if the current Implementation is a good one or needs improvement].

Thank You.

Comment: Just you know `10000` is not one minute. One minute is 60 * 1000.

Comment: Ofcourse sir, as part of testing i wanted to make the api calls for 10 secs.

Comment: *"suggest better ways to do this, Current approaches drawback"* - No, the other way around. List the specific issues you have experienced with your current approach, and the concerns you have about it.

Comment: maybe you should set the interval between completion of last task and starting of new task. otherwise you could double-query by simple lag. so maybe just settimeout with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cron to call the api from nodejs or browser
check [Bree](https://jobscheduler.net/#/?id=real-world-usage) for more information

Comment: is this an answer or a suggestion? [Answering a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: i am answering the question by suggesting a library to do what he want ... he have to go and read the docs to find how-to